# ListView Activity OnItemClickListener Null pointer Exception for TextView

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I want when i click on particular row text should be copy and paste to another activity by intent action.I have implemented the code but one thing is causing null pointer exception.Please help me.

```
//@Override
         // listening to single list item on click
      listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

              // selected item
            TextView  text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
              String lst_txt = text.getText().toString().trim();

             System.out.println("Display text"+lst_txt ); 
              // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
              Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleListItem.class);
              // sending data to new activity
              i.putExtra("product",lst_txt );
              startActivity(i);

          }
        });
```

// here **TextView  text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);**   cause null pointer exception

logcat

```
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at com.example.TwitterTutorial.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:70)
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-12 07:41:25.459: E/AndroidRuntime(2326):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ListActivity activity;
final static String ScreenName = "bane";
final static String LOG_TAG = "rnc";
 ListView listview;
  TextView text;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//  setContentView(R.layout.twit_list);

    // listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


     activity = this;
      listview = this.getListView();
    downloadTweets();

          listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
          if(view != null && view.getContext() != null){

          // selected item
          //text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
         // String lst_txt = text.getText().toString().trim();

           String product = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.targetmonths)).getText().toString();
          //System.out.println("Text"+lst_txt ); 

          // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
          Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleListItem.class);

          // sending data to new activity
          i.putExtra("product",product );
          startActivity(i);
          }

    }

    // download twitter timeline after first checking to see if there is a network connection
    public void downloadTweets() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadTwitterTask().execute(ScreenName);
        } else {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "No network connection available.");
        }
    }

    // Uses an AsyncTask to download a Twitter user's timeline
    private class DownloadTwitterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        final static String CONSUMER_KEY = "3GsPNkJacZedXIwoajycHzkkU";
        final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = "kCsPxxjsfrwba4cSZWW0tmXvaIcWT6r5Gb2HD5VX3RDYoDGRfXG";
        final static String TwitterTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
        final static String TwitterStreamURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... screenNames) {
            String result = null;

            if (screenNames.length > 0) {
                result = getTwitterStream(screenNames[0]);
            }
            return result;
        }

        // onPostExecute convert the JSON results into a Twitter object (which is an Array list of tweets
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Twitter twits = jsonToTwitter(result);

            // lets write the results to the console as well
            for (Tweet tweet : twits) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, tweet.getText());
            }

            // send the tweets to the adapter for rendering
            ArrayAdapter<Tweet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, twits);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

        // converts a string of JSON data into a Twitter object
        private Twitter jsonToTwitter(String result) {
            Twitter twits = null;
            if (result != null && result.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    twits = gson.fromJson(result, Twitter.class);
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                    // just eat the exception
                }
            }
            return twits;
        }

        // convert a JSON authentication object into an Authenticated object
        private Authenticated jsonToAuthenticated(String rawAuthorization) {
            Authenticated auth = null;
            if (rawAuthorization != null && rawAuthorization.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    auth = gson.fromJson(rawAuthorization, Authenticated.class);
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                    // just eat the exception
                }
            }
            return auth;
        }

        private String getResponseBody(HttpRequestBase request) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                String reason = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

                if (statusCode == 200) {

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                } else {
                    sb.append(reason);
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            } catch (ClientProtocolException ex1) {
            } catch (IOException ex2) {
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private String getTwitterStream(String screenName) {
            String results = null;

            // Step 1: Encode consumer key and secret
            try {
                // URL encode the consumer key and secret
                String urlApiKey = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_KEY, "UTF-8");
                String urlApiSecret = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_SECRET, "UTF-8");

                // Concatenate the encoded consumer key, a colon character, and the
                // encoded consumer secret
                String combined = urlApiKey + ":" + urlApiSecret;

                // Base64 encode the string
                String base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(combined.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

                // Step 2: Obtain a bearer token
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(TwitterTokenURL);
                httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Encoded);
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials"));
                String rawAuthorization = getResponseBody(httpPost);
                Authenticated auth = jsonToAuthenticated(rawAuthorization);

                // Applications should verify that the value associated with the
                // token_type key of the returned object is bearer
                if (auth != null && auth.token_type.equals("bearer")) {

                    // Step 3: Authenticate API requests with bearer token
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(TwitterStreamURL + screenName);

                    // construct a normal HTTPS request and include an Authorization
                    // header with the value of Bearer <>
                    httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth.access_token);
                    httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    // update the results with the body of the response
                    results = getResponseBody(httpGet);
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex1) {
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

xml file used to show listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>
```

Data Adapter

```
public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext; 
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    String targetmonths;
    //String img;
    //String targetamount; 
    String[] month;
    //String[] year;
    //String[] amount;
    public DataAdapter(Context c, String[] month) {
        this.month = month;
        //this.year = year;
        //this.amount = amount; 
        mContext = c;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c); 
    } 
    public int getCount() {
        return month.length;
    } 
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    } 
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    } 
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.customgrid, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.month = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.targetmonths); 

            //holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_id); 
        //  holder.amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.targetamount); 




            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        try {

            holder.month.setText(month[position]);




    //      holder.img.setImageResource(img[position]);
        //  holder.amount.setText(amount[position]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return convertView;
    } 
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView month;
    //  ImageView img;
    //  TextView year, amount; 
    }

}
```

Custom Grid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/targetmonths"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="left|center"
                android:paddingBottom="5sp"
                android:paddingLeft="10sp"
                android:paddingRight="5sp"
                android:paddingTop="5sp"
                android:text="hello"
                android:textColor="#ffffcc"
                android:textSize="16sp">
            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u try onListItemClick  listener

Comment: @sakir no its not fit in code

Comment: it is giving red line in eclipse
OnListItemClick cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: You are trying to override the onListItemClick method inside the onCreate method

Comment: if so put it outside of the create method

Comment: @user3682964 check my answer it will solve ur problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get *NPE* because while you creating `Adapter` of that *listview* you are passing `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in this layout there is no `TextView` with id `title`

So change your onItemClick like this

```
//@Override
// listening to single list item on click
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
               int position, long id) {   
     // selected item
     String lst_txt = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().trim();

     System.out.println("Display text"+lst_txt ); 
     // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleListItem.class);
     // sending data to new activity
     i.putExtra("product",lst_txt );
     startActivity(i);
   }
});
```

[***Grep code for android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1***](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
/>
```

Comment: thanks KAushik it worked like charm 
ONE question if you can tell me .
I have links in listview 
But its not show hyperlink.
Can i show the hyperlink ?

Comment: then u have to customize ur Adapter and instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` have to use a custom layout for row

Comment: i agree
but how to customize i changed simple_list_item_1 to other xml with same attributes but eclipse showing red line
How to customize it with custom adapter and show the hyperlinks to work  
   `ArrayAdapter<Tweet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, twits);
   setListAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: can u edit ur question or ask another question with `CustomAdapter` and `custom_layout` code

Comment: i have raised my question  and sorry for late reply here it is [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448641/how-to-implement-customadapter-in-listview-acitivity

Answer (score 2):

Change your Item click listener as below, and see if that works:

**Updated code**

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

        // selected item          
            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.targetmonths);
            String lst_txt = String.valueOf(text.getText());

            System.out.println("Display text"+lst_txt );
            // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleListItem.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            i.putExtra("product",lst_txt );
            startActivity(i); 

    }
});
```

Comment: Below this line  code not execute but it removes error, but still text not get
if (view != null && view.findViewById(R.id.title) instanceof TextView ) {

Comment: can you share your adapter and the xml file used in that

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>
xml file
adapter has no role

Comment: No , I m asking for 2 things, the xml used in your adapter and your Adapter java file

Comment: and share that by editing your question , and leaving acknowledgement comment here..

Comment: Actually the thing is that your adapters xml file is not containing any textview by id R.id.title , that is why you are getting this null

Comment: Meanwhile Based on what you shared I've updated my answer... (actually to be precise just one word I have changed view.findViewById(R.id.targetmonths)).. kindly copy the above and tell if it works

Comment: it not execute the if loop condition

Answer (score 0):

you can use onListItemClick  event

```
protected void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the `getItem()` method in your adapter return null? If so, change it so that it returns a valid view and try again.

Try doing this and tell me what happens:

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
          if(view != null){

          // selected item
          text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
          if(text != null && text.getText() != null){
              String lst_txt = text.getText().toString().trim();

              // String product = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.targetmonth)).getText().toString();
              System.out.println("Text"+lst_txt ); 

              // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
              Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleListItem.class);

              // sending data to new activity
              i.putExtra("product",lst_txt );
              startActivity(i);
          }
          }

      }
```

Also, as a side note, please put a new line before each in-code comment, or avoid them altogether.

Comment: Actually TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title); cause null pointer exception
and no getItem not give null

Comment: Are you 100% sure it is this line and not the next one?

Comment: yes  101 % sure i have tested it. It terminate the program from this side

Comment: And now? I added another condition

Comment: The method getText() is undefined for the type View
it is showing this messagefor the getText condition

Comment: Right, my bad. Try it now

Comment: below this code  -->>  if(text != null && text.getText() != null){
it is not working

Comment: So on this line?
`String lst_txt = text.getText().toString().trim();`

Is it a NullPointer once again?

Comment: actually it is not come under if loop above if loop it is working

Comment: And is there some text displayed in the rows? Or are they blank?

Comment: yes text shows on rows fine
but when i click on some row it is not working 
instead when i put  i.putExtra("product","Message" );
it works for custom string "Message"

Comment: Can you paste the `getView()` method from your adapter?