# Limit the number of Tweets in Twitter Api ver 1.1

Tags: java, android, listview, twitter

I am getting 20 tweets which takes too much time to load. I want to limit the tweets , but don't know where i should limit the tweets in coding . Is there ayone can tell me to limit the tweets please.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ListActivity activity;
    final static String ScreenName = "google";
    final static String LOG_TAG = "rnc";
     ListView listview;
      TextView text;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.twit_list);


          listview = this.getListView();

         activity = this;

        downloadTweets();


          listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int position, long id) {   
                 // selected item
                 String lst_txt = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().trim();


                 // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SingleListItem.class);
                 // sending data to new activity
                 i.putExtra("product",lst_txt );
                 startActivity(i);
               }
            });
    }

    // download twitter timeline after first checking to see if there is a network connection
    public void downloadTweets() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            new DownloadTwitterTask().execute(ScreenName);
        } else {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "No network connection available.");
        }
    }

    // Uses an AsyncTask to download a Twitter user's timeline
    private class DownloadTwitterTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        final static String CONSUMER_KEY = "keyvaluexxxxx";
        final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = "secretkeyxxxxxxx";
        final static String TwitterTokenURL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
        final static String TwitterStreamURL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=";


        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;  
        @Override
        // can use UI thread here
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        //this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Boys.this, ""," Look whose back !! Ok Let me see what i have for you ");  
            try{
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loader_2));
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait ! Unwrapping Something for You...");
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... screenNames) {
            String result = null;

            if (screenNames.length > 0) {
                result = getTwitterStream(screenNames[0]);
            }
            return result;
        }

        // onPostExecute convert the JSON results into a Twitter object (which is an Array list of tweets
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Twitter twits = jsonToTwitter(result);

            // lets write the results to the console as well
            for (Tweet tweet : twits) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, tweet.getText());
            }

            // send the tweets to the adapter for rendering
            ArrayAdapter<Tweet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, twits);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        // converts a string of JSON data into a Twitter object
        private Twitter jsonToTwitter(String result) {
            Twitter twits = null;
            if (result != null && result.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    twits = gson.fromJson(result, Twitter.class);
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                    // just eat the exception
                }
            }
            return twits;
        }

        // convert a JSON authentication object into an Authenticated object
        private Authenticated jsonToAuthenticated(String rawAuthorization) {
            Authenticated auth = null;
            if (rawAuthorization != null && rawAuthorization.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    auth = gson.fromJson(rawAuthorization, Authenticated.class);
                } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                    // just eat the exception
                }
            }
            return auth;
        }

        private String getResponseBody(HttpRequestBase request) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                String reason = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

                if (statusCode == 200) {

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                } else {
                    sb.append(reason);
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            } catch (ClientProtocolException ex1) {
            } catch (IOException ex2) {
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private String getTwitterStream(String screenName) {
            String results = null;

            // Step 1: Encode consumer key and secret
            try {
                // URL encode the consumer key and secret
                String urlApiKey = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_KEY, "UTF-8");
                String urlApiSecret = URLEncoder.encode(CONSUMER_SECRET, "UTF-8");

                // Concatenate the encoded consumer key, a colon character, and the
                // encoded consumer secret
                String combined = urlApiKey + ":" + urlApiSecret;

                // Base64 encode the string
                String base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(combined.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

                // Step 2: Obtain a bearer token
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(TwitterTokenURL);
                httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Encoded);
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=client_credentials"));
                String rawAuthorization = getResponseBody(httpPost);
                Authenticated auth = jsonToAuthenticated(rawAuthorization);

                // Applications should verify that the value associated with the
                // token_type key of the returned object is bearer
                if (auth != null && auth.token_type.equals("bearer")) {

                    // Step 3: Authenticate API requests with bearer token
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(TwitterStreamURL + screenName);

                    // construct a normal HTTPS request and include an Authorization
                    // header with the value of Bearer <>
                    httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + auth.access_token);
                    httpGet.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    // update the results with the body of the response
                    results = getResponseBody(httpGet);
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex1) {
            }
            return results;
        }
    }
}
```

**Twitter.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

// a collection of tweets
public class Twitter extends ArrayList<Tweet> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

**TwitterUser.java**

```
public class TwitterUser {

    @SerializedName("screen_name")
    private String screenName;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("profile_image_url")
    private String profileImageUrl;

    public String getProfileImageUrl() {
        return profileImageUrl;
    }

    public String getScreenName() {
        return screenName;
    }

    public void setProfileImageUrl(String profileImageUrl) {
        this.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl;
    }

    public void setScreenName(String screenName) {
        this.screenName = screenName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Xml file linked with MainActivity.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bis" 

        >

<ListView  
          android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can speicfy count to get the specific no of tweets https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: Thanks @PramodYadav for reply but i am not getting idea how to use it i code

Comment: pass count as no of tweets you want as a parameter your requests to get tweets

Comment: @PramodYadav i have seen the MainActivity and i don't know where to pass the parameter can you just edit the code and put the count feature in coding please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where you are doing your get request you can specify count parameter in the api as parameter to get the specific number of counts

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(TwitterStreamURL + screenName+"&count=10");
```

here i am getting 10 manipulate it according to your usage

Comment: thank you very much it worked !!!
And if u have time can you also consider this question also please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27448641/how-to-implement-customadapter-in-listview-acitivity